# Android show webgl on webview

Tags: android, canvas, webview, webgl

I have URL where is canvas drawed by webGL, I can open and see it with android native browser but there is a problem when I'm trying to open it in my app's webview. It's showing only gray background. Does every browser has it's own webGL or what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your activity (and the webview) is rendering in [hardware accelerated mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html). I imagine it's rendering in software mode where WebGL doesn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't helped :(

Comment: I could be wrong but AFAIK the browser used for WebView is the old Android browser that doesn't support WebGL. Even on newer Android OSes where Chrome is built in. I know they are working on making it so Chrome can be used for WebView but I don't know if that's happened yet.

Comment: @HaykNahapetyan - shoot, my bad, gman was right - WebGL never worked on the WebView, I confused it with canvas.

Answer (score 1):

On android 5, webview will be a first-class citizen: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_the_new_webview_have_feature_parity_with_chrome_for_android_

Answer (score 0):

Android Webview does not support webGL.
According to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) Android L's WebView vill...